# Make Post request with Ktor + Thymeleaf

Tags: kotlin, thymeleaf, ktor

I have the following data class:

```
@Serializable
data class Test(
  var message: String
)
```

with a get and post endpoint configured:

```
    get("/new") {
        call.respond(ThymeleafContent("index", mapOf("test" to Test("Default"))))
    }
    post("/new") {
        try {
            val test = call.receiveParameters()
            println("Parameter: $test")
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
```

The html template contains following part:

```
<div>
  <form th:action="@{new}" th:object="${test}" method="post">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message" th:field="*{message}">

     <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

For the content negogiation I configured a custom converter to see what content is returned from post request:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    register(ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded, object :ContentConverter{
        override suspend fun deserialize(charset: Charset, typeInfo: TypeInfo, content: ByteReadChannel): Any {
            println(charset)
            println(typeInfo)
            println(content.readUTF8Line())

            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun serialize(
            contentType: ContentType,
            charset: Charset,
            typeInfo: TypeInfo,
            value: Any
        ): OutgoingContent? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
}
```

When clicking the submit button on my page there is **only an empty spring submitted**. Is there anything wrong in my configuration?

Comment: I think the problem is that the `name` attribute is missing for the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleksei Tirman suggested the problem was the missing "name" attribute in my input field configuration. Adding the attribute solved the problem:

```
<div>
<form th:action="@{new}" th:object="${test}" method="post">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input name="message" type="text" id="message" placeholder="Text" th:field="*{message}">

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```